# How to get a arraylist<bitmap> from gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I am setting a shuffled arraylist  in grid view after rearranging i want to get the arraylist in the order it is there in gridview . i used getChildAt(position) but it is returning a view.

Here is my code:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < smallimages.size(); i++) {
   //     ArrayList<View>bh=new ArrayList<>(9);
        beforeshuffle.add(smallimages.get(i));
      //  SmallImageAdapter ad=new SmallImageAdapter(c,beforeshuffle);


    }


    Collections.shuffle(smallimages);
    image_grid.setAdapter(new SmallImageAdapter(this, smallimages));
  //  image_grid.setAdapter(new SmallImageAdapter());

    image_grid.setNumColumns((int) Math.sqrt(smallimages.size()));
    image_grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        int counter = 0;
        int firstclick;

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            counter++;
            if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                firstclick = position;
                Bitmap data1 = smallimages.get(position);

            } else {


                    Bitmap swapImage = smallimages.get(position);
                    smallimages.set(position, smallimages.get(firstclick));
                    smallimages.set(firstclick, swapImage);

                   image_grid.invalidateViews();


            }
          //  ArrayList<View>h=new ArrayList<View>(9);

            for (int i=0;i<smallimages.size();i++) {
                aftershuffle.set(i, smallimages.get(i));

            }
            }

    });
```

this aftershulffle is not in the same order the images are place in the 
grid view. So when i check

```
beforeshuffle.get(1).sameAs(aftershuffle.get(1))
```

it returns false

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTag()` and `getTag()` on the view to store custom class objects , For ex: `imageView.setTag(person)`.

Later you can call `Person person = (Person)getChildAt(position).getTag()`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)

Comment: i dont understand what u are saying can u explain